Video / Audio recorded using MediaRecorder has corrupted duration in metadata on IOS devices (webapp)
I am using MediaRecorder() to record audios and videos on my web application. It works fine everywhere apart from IOS devices.
The file sent to backend which I create from the recording blob has corrupted metadata. When I run the following ffmpeg command to check its duration, it turns out to be less than 1 seconds in all cases.
$command = '\-v error \-sexagesimal \-show_entries stream=index,codec_name,start_time,duration:stream_tags=duration ' . $path;

I am not really sure about what the issue may be. Any ideas or leads may be appreciated!
